# Can't color the selected letters and their background with FabricJS 2

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

Hi I want to color just the selected text and its background with FabricJS. In fact letters of text with FabricJS as below:

[image][image]

as very well shown on [their website demo](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html).

But I can't figure out a way to reproduce that.
I've tried with `obj.set("textBackgroundColor", "red")` to color just the background of the selected letters, but it always colors the background of the whole text.

I've tried with `obj.setColor("red")`to color just the selected letters, but it always colors all the letters of the text.
Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edgarkamdem/s6tjz5vo/1/)

Please where I'm wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [setSelectionStyles](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#setSelectionStyles) to set style to selected text, style object as `{textBackgroundColor:value}`.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var itext = new fabric.IText('This is a IText object', {
  left: 100,
  top: 150
});

$('#bg-color').change((e) => {
  let obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  let $this = $(e.currentTarget);
  obj.setSelectionStyles({textBackgroundColor:$this.val()});
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$('#text-color').change((e) => {
  let obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  let $this = $(e.currentTarget);
  obj.setSelectionStyles({fill:$this.val()});
  //obj.textBackgroundColor =$this.val();
  canvas.renderAll();
});


canvas.add(itext);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000"></canvas>

<br>
<div class="controls">
  <p>
    Text color
    <input type="color" id="text-color" data-type="color" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Text background color
    <input type="color" id="bg-color" data-type="color" />
  </p>
</div>
```